# Can`t install "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.Shared.Msi"

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Please understand that I am not good at English.
I'm trying to download Visual Studio, but I get this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jh7w.png)
In the photo, it says "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.Shared.Msi cannot be installed" in Korean.

Could you please tell me a solution to this?

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling. But the same error occurs.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/installation/troubleshoot-installation-issues